# Hardware Modes: Prepositions, Articles, Capitalization

Tags: prepositions, capitalization, definite-articles

I have a lot of uncertainties regarding how to address hardware modes, when it comes to computers, cell phones, circuit boards, etc.

Google provides all kinds of contradicting thoughts and answers either.

---

I would like to break down my question into the four following statements:

- The device is **in** airplane/standby/silent/sleep mode or **on** airplane/standby/silent/sleep mode.

My observations say that *in* is used more frequently.

- The device is **in** sleep/standby or **on** sleep/standby.

As far as I can see, it is most often *in sleep*, but *on standby*. Why is it so?

- Capitalization of modes’ names.

It seems that some people/companies treat modes’ names as proper nouns and capitalize
        modes’ names. Others even capitalize the word *mode* itself.

Put the circuit board in **S**leep **M**ode / **S**leep **m**ode / **s**leep **m**ode.

- **The** in front of airplane/standby/silent/sleep mode.

Most of the time, there is no article and I am ready to accept it. But, this aspect should be 
        looked into to make the question exhaustive.

---

Thank you in advance!